# Quarkus, profile at bean / class level

Tags: quarkus

I would like to initialize the class based on the profile. I have mock service for development and prod has real implementation.

```
public interface Service {
}
```

For dev:

```
//@Profile("Dev") -- not supported in quarkus
@ApplicationScoped
public MockService implements Service {
}
```

For Prod

```
//@Profile("prod") -- not supported in quarkus
@ApplicationScoped
public MainService implements Service {
}
```

Is it possible with quarkus? is there any work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#enabling-beans-for-quarkus-build-profile) part of the documentation.

Your example would likely look like:

```
@IfBuildProfile("dev")
@ApplicationScoped
public MockService implements Service {

}

@DefaultBean
@ApplicationScoped
public MainService implements Service {
}
```